# Allowed definitions in some intuitionistic formal system

Tags: proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I want to introduce a definition, while working with intuitionistic mathematics. I was told that I can define anything, as long as the proofs are valid intuitionistically. But how do I work with a new definition? What if the description of the definition cannot be expressed with intuitionistic logic? Do I make it a set, as in, $x$ is an element defined as $A$ when $x \in A$?

Comment: A def is a def, and not a proof. Thus, tehre are no peculiar intuitionistic "requirements" on def.

Comment: As you said correctly, intuitionstic requirements apply to proof: use of Excluded Middle and existence proofs. Specifically, in intuitionistic math it is not allowed to conclude, from the proof that $\lnot \forall x \lnot Px$, that $\exists x Px$ holds.

Comment: You can still define "$x$ is even" as $\exists y\colon y+y=x$. All fine. Only the methods you are allowed to show that some $x$ is even may be more restrictive ...

Comment: Since the languages are the same, anything that makes sense in one makes sense in the other. It's just that two different definitions that are equivalent classically might not be equivalent in the intuitionistic case.